# Proper syntax of commands in shell

Tags: shell, command

If we have a command such as:

```
command [-p]  [-m  mode] rep
```

Why is:

```
command -m rep
```

not valid?

But

```
command -p rep
```

is valid.

Thank you

Comment: Because the `-m` parameter **requires** a `mode` - as per your definition ..... so you have to use `command -m mode rep` if you want to use `-m`

Comment: With `command -m rep`, most likely "rep" is being taken as the argument for `-m`, leaving no arguments remaining for the command.

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with shell syntax. Maybe it's an option parsing question. To my knowledge there is no standard grammar for documenting option string specifications. The standard for valid option arguments is technically not part of the shell language spec.

Comment: Note that a well written command will respond with a single line error message telling you that the 'rep' argument is missing.  A poorly written command will provide that one line message followed by 70+ lines of a usage statement.  A terribly written program will print that usage statement on stderr.

Comment: I would hope the usage message is printed on standard error if it is triggered by, well, an error. I only want usage printed to standard output if I *ask* for the usage, with something like `command --help`.

Comment: @chepner ...and only for principally direct user-invoked commands I typed into an interactive prompt. You don't really want help output from `/bin/false` :)